# Smash table footnotes of floatrow

Tags: captions, footnotes, floatrow

I am using the [smashcaption](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14272/want-figure-height-to-ignore-side-caption-height?rq=1) redefinition for small images and tables with their caption situated in the margin. It smashes the caption but not additional footnotes. Furthermore, since the caption is smashed the footnotes are overlayed onto the caption. Is it possible to add the footnotes smashed and aligned after the caption?

[image]

Source:

```
  \documentclass[twoside]{book}
  \usepackage[
      letterpaper,
      includemp,
      headheight=0.5in, 
      left=1.25in,
      width=6.75in,
      marginparsep=0.25in,
      marginparwidth=2in,
      bottom=1in,
      top=1in]
      {geometry}

  \usepackage{blindtext}
  \usepackage{floatrow}

  \DeclareFloatSeparators{marginparsep}{\hskip\marginparsep}

  \usepackage{booktabs}
  \usepackage{caption}
  \usepackage{hyperref}

  \makeatletter
  \newcommand*\smashcaption{%
          \def\FR@makecaption##1##2{%
                  \vbox to\z@{%
                          \vss
                          \captionfont
                          {\captionlabelfont##1}\caption@lsep##2%
                          \par
                          \vss
                  }%
          }%
          \caption
  }
  \makeatother
  \begin{document}

  \blindtext[1]

  \thisfloatsetup{%
  floatwidth=\linewidth,
  capposition=beside,
  capbesideposition={bottom,outside},
  facing=yes,
  justification=raggedleft,
  margins=hangoutside,
  capbesidewidth=\marginparwidth,
  capbesidesep=marginparsep
  }
  \begin{table}[h]
  %\ra{1.2}
  {\small
  \begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}
  \toprule
  Library & Purpose  \\
  \midrule
  aa &  AAA\tabularnewline 
  bb\footnote{\url{http://www.abc.com}}\footnote{\url{http://www.abc.com}}\footnote{\url{http://www.abc.com}}
  \footnote{\url{http://www.abc.com}}\footnote{\url{http://www.abc.com}}\footnote{\url{http://www.abc.com}}
  \footnote{\url{http://www.abc.com}}\footnote{\url{http://www.abc.com}}\footnote{\url{http://www.abc.com}}
  \footnote{\url{http://www.abc.com}}\footnote{\url{http://www.abc.com}}\footnote{\url{http://www.abc.com}} &  BBB\tabularnewline 
  cc &  CCC \tabularnewline 
  dd &  DDD \tabularnewline 
  \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}}
  \captionsetup[table]{font={footnotesize,sf},margin=0pt}
  \smashcaption{Some elaborate description about this awesome table.
  Some elaborate description about this awesome table.
  Some elaborate description about this awesome table.
  Some elaborate description about this awesome table.
  Some elaborate description about this awesome table.}
  \end{table}

  \blindtext[1]
  \end{document}
```